# SAS Hash Table (Right Join/Union)

Tags: sas, hashtable

I'm looking to do a lookup that is sort of a hybrid between a join and union. I have a large number of records in my main dataset, so I'm looking to do something that wouldn't be a "brute force" method of a many-to-many matrix.

Here is my main dataset, called 'All', which already contains price for each of the products listed.

```
product date        price   
apple   1/1/2011    1.05    
apple   1/3/2011    1.02
apple   1/4/2011    1.07

pepper  1/2/2011    0.73
pepper  1/3/2011    0.75
pepper  1/6/2011    0.79
```

My other data dataset ('Prices' - not shown here, but contains the same two keys, product and date) contains prices for all products, on each possible date. The hash table look up I would like to create would essentially look up every date in the 'All' table, and output prices for **ALL** products for that date, resulting in a table such as this:

```
product date        price
apple   1/1/2011    1.05    
pepper  1/1/2011    0.71 *
apple   1/2/2011    1.04 *
pepper  1/2/2011    0.73
apple   1/3/2011    1.02
pepper  1/3/2011    0.75
apple   1/4/2011    1.07
pepper  1/4/2011    0.76 *
apple   1/6/2011    1.10 *
pepper  1/6/2011    0.79
```

That is, as long as one product has a date and price specified 'All' table, all other products should pull that in from the lookup table as welll.
The asterisks indicate that the price was looked up from the prices table, and new rows containing prices for products were essentially inserted into the new table.

If hash table are not a great way to go about this, please let me know alternative methods.

Comment: Is your desired WANT dataset just a subset of the PRICES dataset?  (Records from PRICES where DATE is one of the dates in ALL?). How many records in ALL and PRICES?

Comment: For the purposes of this example,  yes. In reality all actually has thousands of transactions per key,  where as prices lists distinct product, date, and price. That's why I thought hash would be solid here.

Comment: But yes the idea is price is needed for ALL products each date as long as AT LEAST ONE product is listed for that date.

Comment: Suggest you edit the data so that ALL has a few transactions per key, and add a PRICES dataset. Are you open to a SQL solution?

Comment: Sure. I understand the brute force method would be to left join on prices and then go through the process of eliminating all the dates in PRICES that are not whatsoever in ALL. I was hoping for something more elegant, but I'm not strict on the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is far from elegant, but curious if the below gives you the desired result?  Since you have multiple records per key in ALL (which I assume you want to maintain), I basically unioned ALL with the records in PRICES that have a date in All, but I added an Except so as to excluded records that were already in ALL.  No idea if this makes sense, or is doing what you want.  Certainly doesn't qualify as 'elegant'.

```
data all;
  input product $7. date mmddyy10. price;
  Y=1;
  format date mmddyy10.;
  cards;
apple  01/01/2011  1.05
apple  01/01/2011  1.05
apple  01/03/2011  1.02
pepper 01/02/2011  0.73
pepper 01/03/2011  0.75
pepper 01/06/2011  0.79
;
run;
data prices;
  input product $7. date mmddyy10. price;
  format date mmddyy10.;
  cards;
apple  01/01/2011  1.05
apple  01/02/2011  1.04
apple  01/03/2011  1.02
apple  01/04/2011  1.07
apple  01/05/2011  1.01
pepper 01/01/2011  0.70
pepper 01/02/2011  0.73
pepper 01/03/2011  0.75
pepper 01/04/2011  0.76
pepper 01/05/2011  0.77
pepper 01/06/2011  0.79
;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select * from all 
  union corr all
  ( (select product,date,price from
      prices
      where date IN (select distinct date from all)
    )
    except corr
    select product,date,price from all
  )
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is pretty nice. The only thing is...the dataset ALL has a bunch more fields that I haven't listed, none of which I want removed. I don't know corr/all keywords that well, but it seems the corr keyword here specifies to overlay only corresponding columns between the 2 tables. ALL has about 30 fields, PRICES only has 6 (of which I can remove all but 3). When I run this, either with or without some combination of corr/all , I still get an error...

Comment: - WARNING: A table has been extended with null columns to perform the EXCEPT set operation.
ERROR: Column 6 from the first contributor of EXCEPT is not the same type as its counterpart from the
       second.
ERROR: Column 7 from the first contributor of EXCEPT is not the same type as its counterpart from the
       second. Is this easily correctable?

Comment: I should add, I don't mind if the "inserted rows" all almost entirely NULL, all that matters is that the product, price, and date fields are populated.

Comment: I updated the code to add an extra variable in ALL, Y.  I changed the except subquery from select * to select product, date, price.  That should avoid the ERROR you are getting.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I figured out that I can correct for this by simply changing the column order. Appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Oh. Probably want CORR on the except. I'll add it.

Comment: Much thanks for your help! I added a follow-up question because the problem became more complex, and I don't think PROC SQL can handle it, since I need to loop-through now...